# multiple adjectives used in a sentence

Tags: word-order

What I'm basically trying to say is "Immoral people that are mentioned (in the previous section of the book)."

> 1 Immoral people mentioned are...
>
> 2 Mentioned immoral people are...

I am confused about which to use between those two sentences. Even though both of them are adjective, it seems to me that "mentioned" explain immoral people, not the people itself, which creates a confusion. I myself would never say "Mentioned and immoral people", so I just cannot find a logical reason to put the "mentioned" in front of immoral as in sentence 2 and regard it as one of the adjectives that describe only the people. However, I don't know if the sentence 1 is correct, since "mentioned" itself is not a phrase, and I am taught that only the adjective phrase with preposition or to infinitive can come after the noun.

Also, here. An instance with an adverb.

> 3 Immoral people already mentioned are...
>
> 4 Already mentioned immoral people are...

When it's mixed up with adverb, it seems even more confusing. I am not sure which is grammatical... Please, give me some grammar rule that governs this type of adjective usage. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> And to our amazement, also in the *third* bar we went to, we saw once again exactly the same group of **previously mentioned immoral people**.

This means that the thing that was previously mentioned is {immoral people}.

Comment: Is it ok to say immoral people previously mentioned?

Comment: That would be more unusual.  "We saw once again exactly the same group of immoral people, previously mentioned."  If I were you I would stick with the vanilla version (with the adjectives *preceding* the noun).

Comment: Thank you! But why do some people say thing like "look at the examples given", not "look at the given example"? Is it a type of version?

Comment: Perhaps you mean *inversion*?  Anyway, the difference between your immoral people example and the "examples given" is that you have much more of a mouthful.  By the way, you might want to ask a Question about "examples given" having the adjective after the noun.  (Although perhaps that has already been asked; but if so, you will discover that, when you start drafting your question, or when people start "voting to close".)  I also wanted to make sure you know about a relatively new sister site, English language learners: ell.stackexchange.com.